# Why android is not posting full email on the server using HttpURLConnection and POST method?

Tags: java, android, django, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to post data on my server using HttpURLConnection and POST method in android. Here is my android code

```
String urlParameters  = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                                    URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");
            byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
            int    postDataLength = postData.length;

//System.out.println(email);           

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
            urlConnection.setUseCaches( false );


            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( postData );
            wr.close();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

In this code where I am printing `email` it shows me the correct full email `abc@xyz.com` but when I receive it on my server it is not full email.

I am using pyhton and django for my website. When I am printing my post data on server it is giving me this result,

```
<QueryDict: {'1e\r\nemail': ['abc@xyz']}>
```

And if you notice, I am receiving `1e` and some times `1c` in the key instead of only `email`. So can anyone tell me what is wrong with my codes? Or why I am receiving this data?

Comment: `it is not full email.`. Well what do you receive instead?

Comment: @greenapps, I receive `abc@xyz` in post data

Comment: You Android code looks ok. But give it a try without that chunked streaming mode and set caches lines.

Comment: Try without the charset too.

Comment: Send some more parameters with their values. Add a dumy parameter BEFORE the email parameter.

Comment: Adding dummy parameter works. But not before email. It works after email.

Comment: What do you mean with 'works'? You should tell what you send and what you receive. Now we have to guess.

Comment: And without chunked streaming did magic. :D :D thanx @greenapps

Comment: Hey @greenapps, I have solved my problem and wrote answer below. Please accept it and approve it as I have mentioned your name. I don't need to add any dummy parameter in the content. Thanx once again.

Comment: I don't know how to invite your. But you can go ahead and write answer @greenapps and I will accept it.

Comment: That was an invitation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Android code looks ok. But give it a try without that chunked streaming mode and set caches lines.